# send recaptcha response with $.ajax data with a var append

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form post with $.ajax for validation. It uses a variable for the "data:" on the POST and appends the info to separate values with-in the variable and then just retrieves them on the server side php. Works great but i am trying to add my reCaptcha response to the data flow to get it to the php side. I've tried many scenarios but so far no luck. If someone has an idea - that would be awesome!! Here is a java snipit:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit_btn").click(function() { 

                //var reCaptcha = grecaptcha.getResponse();
                //alert(reCaptcha); // --> captcha response:

                var proceed = true;
                //simple validation at client's end
                //loop through each field and we simply change border color to red for invalid fields       
                $("#contact_form input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").each(function(){
                    $(this).css('border-color',''); 
                    if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
                        $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                        proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
                    }
                    //check invalid email
                    var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
                    if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))){
                        $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                        proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
                    }   
                });

                if(proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
                {
                   //data to be sent to server 
                   var reCaptcha = grecaptcha.getResponse();         
                    var m_data = new FormData();    
                    m_data.append( 'user_name', $('input[name=name]').val());
                    m_data.append( 'user_email', $('input[name=email]').val());
                    m_data.append( 'country_code', $('input[name=phone1]').val());
                    m_data.append( 'phone_number', $('input[name=phone2]').val());
                    m_data.append( 'subject', $('select[name=subject]').val());
                    m_data.append( 'msg', $('textarea[name=message]').val());
                    m_data.append( 'file_attach', $('input[name=file_attach]')[0].files[0]);
                    m_data.append( 'recaptcha', $(reCaptcha).val());


                    //instead of $.post() we are using $.ajax()
                    //that's because $.ajax() has more options and flexibly.
                    $.ajax({
                      url: 'contact_me.php',
                      data: m_data,
                      processData: false,
                      contentType: false,
                      type: 'POST',
                      dataType:'json',
                      success: function(response){
                         //load json data from server and output message     
                        if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
                            output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
                        }else{
                            output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                        }
                        $("#contact_form #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
                      }
                    });


                }
            });
```

Here is the PHP:

```
//check if its an ajax request, exit if not
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
        'type'=>'error',
        'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
    ));
    die($output); //exit script outputting json data
}


//Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
$user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$country_code   = filter_var($_POST["country_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$phone_number   = filter_var($_POST["phone_number"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$message        = filter_var($_POST["msg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$captcha        = filter_var($_POST["recaptcha"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);




if(strlen($user_name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $captcha));
    die($output);
}
```

What i need to do one way or another is to get the response into the PHP to add to my secret key and the rests to continue the validation of the reCaptcha. What i have going on is that i was trying to bundle the reCaptcha response into the

```
m_data.append( 'recaptcha', $(reCaptcha).val());
```

and then pick it up with:

```
$captcha = filter_var($_POST["recaptcha"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

and then see if it would show in my error field for the name being too short:

```
if(strlen($user_name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $captcha));
    die($output);
}
```

HELP PLEASE!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a very dirty little work around.

I took the reCaptcha pubic response and posted it to a 0px hidden form box and then used the Ajax post to move it to the PHP side.

Not very elegant way of doing it - but it works! Still looking for a better solution that is code based; but until that comes along; this will have to do.